# Recording google meet through Webrtc

Tags: webrtc, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder, openwebrtc, mediarecorder-api

I am trying to record google meet audio and video using webRtc. I found mediaRecorder Api for same. But i am unable to record meeting, as it is only capturing my webcam and audio. How can i record a whole meeting through code in any language?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [Neko](https://github.com/m1k1o/neko) to record conferences. It is like [jibri](https://github.com/jitsi/jibri) but works for all any website!

It is a headless Chromium instance that runs on a server. You launch the neko instance and then join the conference call. You then can capture the web page's audio and video.

You can specify a RTMP output (Twitch, Youtube...) or you can save the files.

Comment: Hi Thank You for suggesting. But if i dont want to use any external tool and build it on my own then is there any way through javascript or any script which can help for same ?